# What is the difference between "dont", "de quoi", "en quoi", and "que ... en" ?

Tags: pronoms-relatifs

I'd like to know when to use each of these four different relative pronouns.

"The only thing we need to be worried about is ... money."

> « La seule chose **dont** on doit se soucier, c'est... l'argent. »
>
> « La seule chose **de quoi** on doit se soucier, c'est... l'argent. »
>
> « La seule chose **en quoi** on doit se soucier, c'est... l'argent. »
>
> « La seule chose **qu**'on **en** doit se soucier, c'est... l'argent. »

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La bonne expression est :

> La seule chose **dont** on doit se soucier, c'est... l'argent.

Elle vient de la contraction *de quoi* (qui est incorrect).

Les autres propositions sont incorrectes.

La construction se fait en prenant la construction directe, et en regardant la **préposition** :

> On doit se soucier **de** l'argent.

Puis en inversant:

- *de* (*quoi, qui*) => *dont*
- *à => auquel, à laquelle, à quoi*
- *sur => sur qui, sur quoi*
- etc.